# Unable to connect to TFS in VS 2011Beta

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I tried to open an existing solution (which is under source control) in Visual Studio 2011Beta. It gave me the next error:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding
>   information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover
>   this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings
>   are missing will be treated as not under source control.

Then I tried to connect to Team Foundation Server manually by entering credentials which 100% worked when used with Visual Studio 2010 Team Client, but I receive the error again:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

The source control I tried to connect is TFS 2005. Is there a way to connect it from VS 2011Beta?

Comment: With VS11 being a *beta* not all the forwards/backwards compatibility bits have been done, or how many will be done. As all TFS clients (with compatibility patches) can work with later TFS versions, perhaps it is time to upgrade (TFS2005 --> 2008 is relatively easy, to 2010 is harder).

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. It seems VS11 has the same problem with TFS 2008 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is really an issue. After googling a bit I found [Cannot connect to Existing TFS with VS 2011 Beta](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727349/cannot-connect-to-existing-tfs-with-vs-2011-beta) feedback on Microsoft Connect:

> When opening an existing 2010 solution , project cannot connect to
>   existing TFS server (Non 2011 TFS Beta installation). In VS 2011 when
>   trying to add a connection manually to the TFS server it results in
>   error TF31002. Verified that the connection setting is valid as VS
>   2010 is using it with no issue.

The answer from Microsoft was in their style:

> We do not support Dev11 clients communicating with TFS 2005 server.

and the ticked now is closed as *by design*. 

Thank you Microsoft for always taking care of us.